# How to properly create unit test for logic inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I'm working on an existing NodeJS web service using HapiJS, Hapi Lab for testing along with Sinon. The service connects to a Postgres DB using massiveJs. There's a method implemented by someone else, that doesn't have unit tests. Now I'm reusing this method and I want to implement some unit tests for it.
This method executes a massivejs transaction inside of it, persisting to several tables.

```
async createSomething(payload) {

    const { code, member } = payload;

    const foundCompany = await this.rawDb.ethnics.tenants.findOne({ code });

    if (foundCompany && foundCompany.companyId) {

        const { companyId } = foundCompany;
        const { foreignId } = member;

        return await this.rawDb.withTransaction(async (tx) => {

            const foundMember = await tx.ethnics.members.findOne({ foreign_id: foreignId, company_id: companyId });

            if (!foundMember) {

                //some business logic...
                const newMember = await tx.ethnics.members.insert(member);
                //more business logic persisting to other tables...
                return newMember;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Problem is, I don't know how to stub stuff only inside the arrow function, without stubbing the entire arrow function. I just want to stub the calls of tx. I also don't want to use a database but stub the rawDb property. Is that doable from unit testing perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is doable. There are 2 alternatives:

1. Stub MassiveJS methods directly.

Example to stub massive method *findOne*:

```
const massive = require('massive');
const sinon = require('sinon');

// Stub massive.Readable class method findOne.
// You need to find where is the real method findOne and stub it.
const stub = sinon.stub(massive.Readable, 'findOne');
// You can resolve it.
stub.resolves();
// Or you can throw it.
stub.throws(new Error('xxx'));
```

2. Use pg in memory for test.

Just for testing purpose, you can use module like: [test-pg-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-pg-pool) or [pg-mem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-mem). Before testing, start the test pg and after the test finish, destroy it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've already stubbed dependencies in the past (like logger) but didn't come to my mind to do it in this scenario.